# Multiple laser beams from one object using raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have an object on which I want multiple laser beams instead of only one.

[image]

The following code shows a line beam only one side. But expected from for sides.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour
{

    private LineRenderer lr;
    private bool clicked = false;
    RaycastHit rh;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    }




    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (clicked)
        {

            lr.SetPosition(0, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), -transform.up, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider)
                {
                    lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
                }
            }
            else lr.SetPosition(1, -transform.up * 5000);


            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), transform.up, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider)
                {
                    lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
                }
            }
            else lr.SetPosition(1, transform.up * 5000);

           if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), transform.right, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider)
                {
                    lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
                }
            }
            else lr.SetPosition(1, transform.right * 5000);

           if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), -transform.right, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider)
                {
                    lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
                }
            }
            else lr.SetPosition(1, -transform.right * 5000);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to shoot two beams at the same time(if so then which direction? up down or left right) or four beams in simultaneously in up,down,left &right?

Comment: @killer_mech four beams simultaneously

Comment: You might want to remodify the question then, it was confusing as you said "But expected two."

Comment: @killer_mech done

Comment: You have one property "lr" and you want it to represent four beams...

Comment: I may be wrong but can't you make 4 empty GameObjects, position them correctly then do your raycasts therefrom?

Comment: By the way, `+ new Vector3(0, 0, 0)` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public LineRenderer lr_up;
public LineRenderer lr_down;
public LineRenderer lr_left;
public LineRenderer lr_right;

private bool clicked = false;

RaycastHit rh;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (clicked)
    {
        lr_up.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lr_down.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lr_left.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lr_right.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                lr_up.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            }
        }
        else lr_up.SetPosition(1, -transform.up * 5000);


        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                lr_down.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            }
        }
        else lr_down.SetPosition(1, transform.up * 5000);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                lr_left.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            }
        }
        else lr_left.SetPosition(1, transform.right * 5000);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                lr_right.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            }
        }
        else lr_right.SetPosition(1, -transform.right * 5000);
    }
}
```

This is your corrected code. You will need four line renderers to represent four beams. You cannot have one line renderer and expect it to shoot in four direction. Create four empty child in your current object. Assign the line renderer component & assign them respective line renderer in script. The rest of the code will take care of setting the beams.

Comment: Oh oversight on my part, thanks derHugo. I just added the four line renderers but didnt check the validity of code.